# How can I persistently boot into linux-grsec?

Tags: boot, grub, grsecurity

I've installed the `linux-grsec` kernel on my machine via `pacman`. While I can edit `grub`'s settings at boot time by hitting '`e`' at the bootloader menu, the updates I make specifying which kernel and ramdisk to use are ephemeral, and don't persist after a reboot.

How can I make these changes persistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In /etc/default/grub  Section `GRUB_DEFAULT`

> 'GRUB_DEFAULT'
>        The default menu entry.  This may be a number, in which case it
>        identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero,
>        or the title of a menu entry, or the special string 'saved'.  Using
>        the id may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as the default
>        even though there may be a variable number of entries before it.

More Informations are shown by command `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`

After modifying don't forget to update your Grub-Konfiguration. `update-grub`